# saving output of splot(GNUPlot)

Tags: gnuplot

I have two files `same_2` and `diff_2` and I plot the data in these files with this command using GNUPlot.

`splot "./same_2" with points, "./diff_2" with points`

I have the 3D plot. How can I save it, so that I can view it later. I do not want to store it as an image, and that's what I keep getting on search.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an option in gnu plot's command set: `set term` which can be used to set the output to a variety of formats, including PS, PNG, and others.

Details are at the [gnuplot tutorial](http://www.math.utk.edu/~vasili/refs/How-to/gnuplot.print.html).

There's a help system, if you type `help set` at the gnuplot command line, you will get more details.

To add a 3d output terminal for something like VRML or PovRay, you'll need to apply [a custom patch](http://t-kita.net/gnuplot_povrml/).

Comment: The problem is I cannot rotate whatever is produced, like I can do in the `gnuplot` window.

Comment: I added a link to output to 3d file types.

Comment: I got the following error while applying the patch.
`can't find file to patch at input line 4
Perhaps you used the wrong -p or --strip option?` I am using gnuplot v4.4

Comment: The patch is for version 4.0 of gnuplot.  You may have to downgrade, or do some of your own development to make it work fully.